# How to center UIButton programmatically in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating `ViewCell` programmatically and I want to center `UIButton` to `UIImageView`, so it would look like this:

```
 -----------------------------
|                             |
|                             |
|            Button           |
|                             |
|                             |
 -----------------------------
```

To achieve that first in init method I create `UIImageView` and `UIButton`:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "button_image"), for: .normal)
button.contentMode = .center
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 42)
```

And then I add some constraints, in case of button and imageview I added these constraints:

```
button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
button.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

But as result I always crash my app.

How can I achieve centered button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.

Comment: Where should set it? I mean to what view element?

Comment: For every element with constraints.

Comment: That definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

Once your view loads completely, do this

```
button.center = imageView.center
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
button.center = imageView.center
```

It sets the center of the button frame to that of the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.center` property like

```
myButton.center = self.image.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

button.frame = imageV.frame